# Why programs often fail to run when started by `daemon`?

Tags: linux, gui, daemon

I do `daemon -f -i ./some_gui_program` - it starts.

I do `daemon -i ./some_gui_program` - nothing visible happens.

Why I can't start GUI programs detached on Linux this way? What's the use of daemon's `-f` option if it changes behaviour that much?

Comment: What are some GUI programs that don't work?  What happens in this case?

Answer (score 3):

First, some basic information about different types of programs:

A GUI program is usually used to process input from the user. In order to do this, it needs some sort of X server, which handles interactions with keyboard and mouse. 
When you start a GUI program, it will inherit a lot of settings from your X session. It won't work unless the program has access to those settings and to your X session.

There are a lot of other programs that don't require X or a GUI. Those are usually meant to either be run from a command line, or to be run as a daemon. Programs that are run from the command line will receive input via STDIN and (usually) print output back via STDOUT.

Other programs don't require input/output via STDIN/STDOUT. One example of this is a web server - its input will be received through a TCP session, and output will be sent through a TCP connection and to log files.

So, in answer to your questions:

> Why I can't start GUI programs detached on Linux this way?

When you run daemon, you are essentially disconnecting the program from your own GUI and from your input/output. That's why a program that requires a GUI or a connection to your STDIN/STDOUT doesn't work with daemon. Only the last type of program is suitable for being run completely as a daemon.

> What's the use of daemon's -f option if it changes behaviour that much?

Changing the behaviour in that way is exactly what `-f` is for - it doesn't detach the daemonized process completely, and thus it can be used for programs that require e.g. connection to your current X session.

Typing `man daemon` in an xterm will give you a lot of information on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want a program to run in the background when you don't expect to interact with it. Daemons are a classical example for this. Typically they are started during the boot process and don't expect any input from the user (at least not via command line). GUIs on the other hand are the very definition of something that needs to interact with the user.

In regards to your question about programs failing in daemon mode, it comes down to three things:

- Starting the program in the wrong way, e.g. not using the proper start script
- Environment, e.g. variables like `$HOME` is not set up correctly
- Bad programming practices

Without knowing what exact program you are referring to, we obviously can't answer you question definitively. However, generally speaking, it wouldn't make too much sense to run GUIs in the background without any way of interaction.

Comment: But the one who asked the question is talking about a `daemon` program (it's its name, so it can't be substituted by `sshd`, I believe), which accepts an `-f` option and another program to start.

Comment: The poster should have explained better, but I think they're taking about this program that's actually called `daemon`. http://libslack.org/daemon/manpages/daemon.1.html

Comment: Ok, to clear things up, I removed the paragraph about ssh as it was probably too confusing.